# Environment variable not picked up by Tomcat 7 on OpenShift

Tags: tomcat, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am running a JSF application on the JBoss EWS 2.0 cartridge in OpenShift, and the time has come to set the application to run in Production mode. To keep my application as portable as possible, I would like to do this by setting the `faces.PROJECT_STAGE` environment variable.

First I tried using `rhc set-env ...` or `rhc env set ...` but it didn't like the "dot" in the variable name. So I created this environment variable:

```
rhc env set facesPROJECT_STAGE=Production -a myapp
```

and then SSH'ed into my OpenShift account to change the file `facesPROJECT_STAGE` in `.env/user_vars` to `facesPROJECT_STAGE`. Running `rhc env list -a myapp` then shows me:

`faces.PROJECT_STAGE=Production`

However when I restart my application, it doesn't pick up the `faces.PROJECT_STAGE` environment variable. Doing a `rhc app reload -a myapp` doesn't help either. If it makes any difference my application is currently not auto-scalable.

Comment: Do you need an environment variable, or a Java system property?

Comment: My bad, I was mentally equating env variable with system property. I used `rhc env set JAVA_OPTS_EXT=-Dfaces.PROJECT_STAGE=Production -a myapp` and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use system properties instead of environment variables. Set the `JAVA_OPTS_EXT` environment variable to `-Dfaces.PROJECT_STAGE=Production -a myapp` like this:

```
export JAVA_OPTS_EXT=-Dfaces.PROJECT_STAGE=Production
```

... and you should be good to go. (You may need to do something else to get that value to stick for for all time for your process -- and processes launched in the future).